# how to create and run web application sharp develop tool?

Tags: iis, web-applications, sharpdevelop

I am new for the Sharp develop tool. I need to create the web application and set it to local IIS. with Default.aspx as default page in VS. but I could not found option for the same. what is configuration required to be make web application runnable in sharp develop tool with local IIS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the team blog to get the information,

http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/marcueusebiu/archive/2011/01/12/full-web-server-iis-5-1-7-amp-iis-express-support-in-sharpdevelop.aspx

SharpDevelop has IIS and IIS Express support.

Comment: very nice link you shared. but as i followed this, i could not set the default.aspx page ? how to do that ?

Comment: That's something you should report to SharpDevelop guys as a feature request/bug report, via the official channel, http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/19.aspx